# segmentation fault when calling below function

Tags: c, pointers

```
unsigned int **city_array(const char *file, size_t *s) {
        FILE* file = fopen("file", "r");
        int size=*s;
        fscanf(file,"%d",&size);

        int** arr = ( int**)malloc(size * sizeof (int*));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            arr[i] = (int*)malloc(size * sizeof (int));
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){   
            for(int j=0;j<size;j++){
                if(i==j){
                    arr[i][j]=0;
                }
                else{
                    arr[i][j]=1;
                }
            }
        }  
    return arr; 
    }
```

i am trying to read size from text file and set it to pointer variable s(size_t *s) and allocate a 2D array of size 's' with 0 and 1 and return array.

text file contains just an integer which is size of 2d array(rows and columns)

```
 warning: returning ‘int **’ from a function with incompatible return type ‘unsigned int **’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Getting this warning and segmentation fault when i run the code. Not sure where i'm getting sementation fault.

Comment: It is not productive to debug incomplete code snippets. Please provide a [mre]. Also, please do a bit more debugging. As a minimum, run your program in a debugger, get the stack trace and post it in the question.

Comment: Also, suggest you add basic error checking code. Specifically, should check `fopen` and `fscanf` for failures. That will likely show you that `fopen` is failing due to a typo- leave you to figure out exactly why.

Comment: Did you mean to use the passed in parameter named `file` instead of the literal `"file"` here? `FILE* in_file = fopen("file", "r");` Always check if a file opened before attempting to use the pointer.

Comment: Latest update suggests you didn't get the hints. So explicitly `fopen("file", "r")` needs to be `fopen(file, "r")`. And change the `file` local variable name back to what it was previously so that it doesn't clash with the function parameter `file`.

Comment: By the usual definition, a 2D array would be contiguous (eg: a chessboard). From most squares of a chessboard, adding 8 will take you to the next 'rank'. Not so with this "2D array". Are you sure you want 'n' separate vectors (ie: 'n' separate 1D arrays)??

Comment: The reason for that warning is rather obvious: `unsigned int` is not the same as `int`. Decide what kind of values you want to store in the allocated memory. Then use that type consistently.

Comment: After your edit, you are even hiding the parameter `file` passed to your function by a local variable `file`. That is a no-go. Also it is very likely not what you want, as explained in multiple comments above.